# Как центрировать список в Python без модулей?

Tags: python

Мне надо центрировать список в Python без модулей, например:

```
 │     1     │     2     │     3     │ 
 │     4     │     5     │     6     │ 
 │     7     │     8     │     9     │ 

table_data = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'], 
    ['7', '8', '9']
]
```

Таким образом, чтобы количество столбцов было не ограничено.

У меня получилось сделать с таким кодом, но вывод немного не такой, как хотелось бы

```py
def make_table(): 
    table_data = [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'], 
        ['7', '8', '9']
    ]
    for row in table_data:
        print(" │ {: >5} │ {: >5} │ {: >5} │ ".format(*row))
```

```
 │     1 │     2 │     3 │ 
 │     4 │     5 │     6 │ 
 │     7 │     8 │     9 │
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы колонка была в таблице по размеру наибольшего объекта списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298128/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Для форматирования по центру используйте знак `^` вместо `>`:

```
table_data = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'], 
    ['7', '8', '9']
]
for row in table_data:
    print(" │ {:^5} │ {:^5} │ {:^5} │ ".format(*row))
```

```
 │   1   │   2   │   3   │ 
 │   4   │   5   │   6   │ 
 │   7   │   8   │   9   │
```

Comment: но моя цель сделать так, чтобы при любом размере текста, остальные поля этой колонки ставали такого же размера, а не так

Comment: @gylah-u про это в вопросе ничего не сказано, там только туманная фраза "но вывод немного не такой, как хотелось бы". Чтобы вас правильно понимали, нужно в вопросе писать конкретно, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Посчитать максимальную длину текста для каждого столбца, затем отцентровать каждый элемент согласно посчитанной длине для этого столбца, а затем склеить список используя `join()`.

```
def make_table(): 
    table_data = [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', 'sdfdfdfs', '6'], 
        ['7', '8', '9']
    ]
    lengths = [max(map(len, col))+2 for col in zip(*table_data)]
    for row in table_data:
        print('|'+'|'.join(txt.center(lengths[i]) for i, txt in enumerate(row))+'|')

make_table()
```

```
| 1 |    2     | 3 |
| 4 | sdfdfdfs | 6 |
| 7 |    8     | 9 |
```

Если нужно чтобы вообще все колонки были равны, то просто посчитать максимальную длину текста во всех ячейках.

```
    length = max(max(map(len, row)) for row in table_data) + 2
    for row in table_data:
        print('|'+'|'.join(txt.center(length) for i, txt in enumerate(row))+'|')
```

```
|    1     |    2     |    3     |
|    4     | sdfdfdfs |    6     |
|    7     |    8     |    9     |
```

Comment: но моя цель сделать так, чтобы при любом размере текста, остальные поля этой колонки ставали такого же размера, а не так, чтобы оно смещалось

Comment: @gylah-u Какие "остальные поля" какой "колонки"?

Comment: хотелось бы показать на скриншоте

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Rkl6pCX
надо чтобы колонка с 8 и 2 была такой же длинной как и та, что между ними, то есть добавить х количество отступов туда

Comment: @gylah-u Обновил ответ.

Comment: Ячейки не должны быть равными. У меня должно быть что-то вроде:
`
https://imgur.com/sODlrY4
`