# Как сделать, чтобы колонка была в таблице по размеру наибольшего объекта списка?

Tags: python

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы в таблице, когда любая из частей колонки была больше остальных, то колонка полностью становилась её размеров, а не указаных.

```py
def make_table():
    table_data = [
        ['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9']
    ]
    print('┌', end = '')
    print("─"*9, end='')
    print('┬', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┬', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┐')
    print("│", end=' ')
    headers = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    for column in headers:
        print(column.center(8), end="│")
    print('')
    print('├', end='')
    print("─"*9, end='')
    print('┼', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┼', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┤')
    for row in table_data:
        print("│ ", end=' ')
        for column in row:
            print(column.center(6, ' '), end=" │ ")
        print('')
    print('└', end = '')
    print("─" * 9, end = '')
    print('┴', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┴', end='')
    print("─"*8, end='')
    print('┘')
make_table()
```

я получаю в таком случае:
[image: Правильный вывод]

Но стоит мне сделать что-то большим я получаю?
[image: Не правильный вывод]

Comment: тут только один путь, заранее перед печатью пройти по всему массиву данных и посчитать максимальную длину значений для каждой колонки. А печатать уже вторым проходом

Comment: @gylah-u Так я дал же ответ на этот вопрос в [вашем предыдущем точно таком же вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298093/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-python-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9).

Comment: Может уже хватит изобретать [велосипед](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/)? ;)

Comment: @MaxU Может у человека табу на слово import... :)

Comment: @GrAnd, когда я вижу этот код из вопроса у меня начинается легкий приступ идиосинкразии. Так что лучше уж одна строка импорта и пара строк читабельного кода :-D

Comment: @MaxU, по условиям у меня нету доступа к библиотекам кроме стандартных :)

Comment: @gylah-u, ну тогда подсмотрите как это сделано в исходниках `prettytable` и сделайте так же - заодно посмотрите на пример хорошо и профессионально написанного кода ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ладно, поизобретаю велосипед...

```
def make_table(header, data): 
    cols = len(header)
    lengths = [max(map(len, map(str, col)))+2 for col in zip(*([header] + data))]
    print    ('┌'+'┬'.join('─'*lengths[i]              for i      in range(cols))      +'┐')
    print    ('│'+'│'.join(str(txt).center(lengths[i]) for i, txt in enumerate(header))+'│')
    print    ('├'+'┼'.join('─'*lengths[i]              for i      in range(cols))      +'┤')
    for row in data:
        print('│'+'│'.join(str(txt).center(lengths[i]) for i, txt in enumerate(row))   +'│')
    print    ('└'+'┴'.join('─'*lengths[i]              for i      in range(cols))      +'┘')


make_table(['val1', 'val2', 'val333333333'],
           [['1', '2', '3'],
            ['4', 55555555, '6'], 
            [7, 8, 9]]
)
```

```
┌──────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ val1 │   val2   │ val333333333 │
├──────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│  1   │    2     │      3       │
│  4   │ 55555555 │      6       │
│  7   │    8     │      9       │
└──────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: вы как автор кода, можете рассказать тайну как убрать центрирование и возможность использования обычных цифр, не стрингов?

Comment: @gylah-u Вместо `txt.center(...)` по аналогии использовать `txt.ljust(...)` или `txt.rjust(...)` для выравнивания влево и вправо соответственно. Чтобы принимало не только строки - принудительно преобразовывать `txt` в `str(txt)` прежде чем работать со строкой дальше. Т.е. писать `str(txt).center(...)`. Ах да, ещё в `map(len, col)` тоже преобразовать в строки прежде чем считать длину, т.е. записать так `map(len, map(str, col))`.

Comment: И ещё, когда у меня текст в колонке больше самого названия колонки, получается следующее https://imgur.com/a/ld0H50m

Comment: @gylah-u Если использовать функцию, что я написал - так не получится. В ней считается и используется максимальная длина текста в каждой колонке для всех ячеек этой колонки.