# Вывод динамического списка в таблицу

Tags: python

После выполнения некоторых операций у меня образуются несколько списков. Я написал код для вывода этих списков в виде таблицы.

```
s = ['Q:', " ".join(map(str, Q))]
data = [['TC:', " ".join(map(str, TC))], ['FC', " ".join(map(str, FC))], 
        ['VC', " ".join(map(str, VC))],['ATC'," ".join(map(str,  ATC))], 
        ['MC', " ".join(map(str, MC))]]
print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers, tablefmt='presto'))
```

Результат сейчас выводится так:

```
 Q:  | 0 1 2 3
---------------------+------------------
 TC: | 5 6 7 8
 FC  | 5 5 5 5
 VC  | 0 1 2 3
 ATC | None 6.0 3.5 2.6666666666666665
 MC  | None 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Как исправить, чтобы выводилось так:

```
 Q:  | 0     |1    |2    |3
---------------------+---------------------------------
 TC: | 5     |6    |7    |8
 FC  | 5     |5    |5    |5
 VC  | 0     |1    |2    |3
 ATC | None  |6.0  |3.5  |2.6666666666666665
 MC  | None  |1.0  |1.0  |1.0
```

Comment: Как вариант, использовать что-то вроде `map(lambda x: f"| {str(x):<5} ", ...)` вместо `map(str, ...)`.

Comment: Ну или вот другой мой [ответ на аналогичную тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298128/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0/1298139#1298139).

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

тут можно поиграться с форматными строками:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
line = "VALUE: |" + '|'.join([f'{value}    ' for value in lst])
```

результат:

```py
VALUE: |1    |2    |3    |4    |5
```

можно конечно совсем запариться и высчитывать длину каждого числа, чтоб если какое то имеет слишком большую точность то строки не поехали, но это уже на усмотрение. а так если все данные примерно равны можно просто высчитать длину отступов в пробелах и регулировать ее тут `f'{value}___'`